# kendoTabStrip - how to hide and show individual tabs dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, kendo-ui, strip

I am using the kendoTabStrip on my page and need to show and hide a specific tab based on actions on the page. How is this done? My code below:

  Data Grid
- Data Chart

@* Data Grid *@
    
      @(Html.Partial("_Grid", Model))
    

    @* Charts *@
    
        @(Html.Partial("_Chart"))
    


$("#dataTabStrip").kendoTabStrip();

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. Probably not the cleanest way, but it will work.
Notice "eq(1)" This will select the second tab.

```
var viewtabstrip = $(".viewselector").kendoTabStrip({}).data("kendoTabStrip");

viewtabstrip.disable($(".viewselector ul").children().eq(1));
```